# javascript and css not applicable on ajax based dynamically populated tag by jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, jsp

I am dynamically populating select tag by jsp calling through ajax.
It seems that style(css) and behavior(javascript) is not applicable on newly populated select tag, while the same is working for statically populated select tag.
select tag code is

```
<div id='state' > 
  <select name='state' data-placeholder='select Courses' style='width:350px;' class='chosen-select' multiple tabindex='6'>
    <option value='-1'>Nothing Here</option>  
  </select>  
</div>
```

Above div id is populated with same select nomenclature by calling jsp via ajax.
css file that defines style of select used is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/chosen.css">
```

javascript file used for behavior of select is

```
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var config = {
  '.chosen-select'           : {},
  '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
  '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
  '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
  '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"95%"}
}
for (var selector in config) {
  $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
}
```

and state.jsp is called via through below code to populate select

```
function showState(str){
 ....
 ....
var url="state.jsp";
url +="?count=" +str;
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}

  function stateChange(){   
  if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){   

  document.getElementById("state").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
  }   
  }
```

How javascript behavior can be maintained despite of dynamic creation of tag?
I have seen answers discussing about delegation , bind, live and on but still i am confused. Please help me with this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a working example it's hard to be certain, but I believe the problem will stem from the order in which things are happening.  Your js is running at page load, so it will apply style and events to whatever it finds at that time, which will be nothing because your ajax request hasn't returned the data yet.

So after you write to the DOM with the ajax data, you'll need to re-run your script to apply style and events to the newly created elements.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I have written js function and called it after writing DOM